# Is it possible to merge/obsolete Solaris SVR4 packages?

Tags: installation, package, solaris

Package formats like RPM and DPKG have the concept of 'replaces' or 'obsoletes', which can be used when merging one package into another.

Do Solaris SVR4 packages support a similar concept?  The closest I can find is the 'depend' file, which allows me to define a conflict, but not how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.   The Solaris installer kept track of these separately from the package system itself in order to do Solaris upgrades, and only for the packages that were part of the OS.   The provided SVR4 package commands have no notion of upgrades, nor of dependency resolution, only install & remove of the exact versions specified of the exact packages specified.

These are among the many features added by the IPS package system that replaced SVR4 packages in Solaris 11.